TypeScript Azure Function Not Registering in Function App
After running npm run build to generate JavaScript files from my TypeScript source code, I then run the following commands successfully to deploy my TypeScript Azure Function:
func azure functionapp publish myFunctionApp
However, after the command completes, no functions are listed in the output.  When I view the function app in the Azure console, I also do not see any functions listed.
Oddly, if I click Download App Content, I see the function code.  It seems that the TypeScript function is deployed successfully, but does not register with the Function App.
I've also successfully deployed using this command, but I still don't see any functions listed under the Function App in the Azure console.
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g my-new-resource-group1 -n myFunctionApp --src ../myFunction.zip
I should note that my function's root is nested inside of a larger mono repo, but the function's root directory contents do follow the expected function project structure.  Just mentioning that in case it is a problem.
How do I get the function to register with the Function App successfully?

I was able to register the function successfully by creating my project from scratch following the accepted answer in this link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1402890/azure-function-is-not-deployed-from-vs-no-http-tri
Note that my local.settings.json looks like this instead of what is shared in the link's accepted answer.  Replace the placeholder with your Azure storage account connection string.
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<your Azure storage account connection string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }

}


Late answer but three days of bug hunting (I had the same problem as you) and I found it:
Somewhere on the internet I found a comment in an issue, that Azure functions v4 is only rolled out to US West 2. In my case using Europe as hosting location, functions never got registered.
When I switched back to v3 using the module.exports... syntax and the index.js + function.json file structure, the functions were registered upon deployment.

Wow, what a terrible-sounding experience.  I'm glad you got it resolved though!
